# Migrate Printers using the command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, build-automation

Im looking to copy the printers from the users old workstation to the new workstation

I have tried the built in printbrm.exe  but I need something that will work reliably and simply.

Are there any command line solutions that can do this or a sol;ution that that can be run from a batch file?

Thanks for reading

Confuseis

Comment: The same OS running _old workstation_ and _new workstation_? Then some of `.vbs` scripts under `C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts` could help... However, I do not understand your _to copy the printers_ statement. What to copy? Drivers? Names? ...

Comment: Mainly I mean just to copy the printers.  Its possible the architecture on the desntiation system could be different e.g   32bit /64bit.   So I just want to copy over the printers & their ports, they can always pull the driver back down from the print server.